# removing duplicates with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've got the following array:

```
data = [{
  name: "Robert",
  urls: [{
    provider: "facebook",
    url: "http://twitter.com/rob"
  }]
}, {
  name: "Robert",
  urls: [{
    provider: "youtube",
    url: "http://youtube.com/robs"
  }]
}, {
  name: "Linda is a perfect duplicate",
  urls: [{
    provider: "youtube",
    url: "http://youtube.com/lindaTube"
  }]
}, {
  name: "Linda is a perfect duplicate",
  urls: [{
    provider: "youtube",
    url: "http://youtube.com/lindaTube"
  }]
}]
```

I need to build a new array based on `data` that look like this one:

```
newdata = [{
  name: "Robert",
  urls: [{
    provider: "facebook",
    url: "http://twitter.com/rob"
  }, {
    provider: "youtube",
    url: "http://youtube.com/robs"
  }]
}, {
  name: "Linda is a perfect duplicate",
  urls: [{
    provider: "youtube",
    url: "http://youtube.com/lindaTube"
  }]
}];
```

i'm using `.merge` and `.keyBy` but `[urls]` is always overwritten.
here is how i do it:

```
let newdata = [];
data.forEach((val, i) => {
  newdata = _.values(_.merge(
            _.keyBy(newdata, 'name'),
            _.keyBy(data[i], 'name')
            ));
});
```

Comment: Check: [Merge duplicate objects in single array using lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028895/removing-duplicates-with-lodash) you just need to remove duplicate urls.

Comment: what if 2 different name have same url object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`lodash#groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) to group the collection by `name`. Rebuild the group into an array using [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map). Use [`lodash#flatMap`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMap) to obtain all urls into a flattened format, so we can remove all the duplicates through [`lodash#uniqWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqwith) that has a [`lodash#isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual) comparator function.

```
var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('name')
  .map((group, name) => ({
    name,
    urls: _(group).flatMap('urls').uniqWith(_.isEqual).value()
  }))
  .value();
```

```js
var data = [{
  name: "Robert",
  urls: [{
    provider: "facebook",
    url: "http://twitter.com/rob"
  }]
}, {
  name: "Robert",
  urls: [{
    provider: "youtube",
    url: "http://youtube.com/robs"
  }]
}, {
  name: "Linda is a perfect duplicate",
  urls: [{
    provider: "youtube",
    url: "http://youtube.com/lindaTube"
  }]
}, {
  name: "Linda is a perfect duplicate",
  urls: [{
    provider: "youtube",
    url: "http://youtube.com/lindaTube"
  }]
}];

var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('name')
  .map((group, name) => ({
    name,
    urls: _(group).flatMap('urls').uniqWith(_.isEqual).value()
  }))
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>

<!--
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

How about it?

```js
var data = [{
  name: "Robert",
  urls: [{
    provider: "facebook",
    url: "http://twitter.com/rob"
  }]
}, {
  name: "Robert",
  urls: [{
    provider: "youtube",
    url: "http://youtube.com/robs"
  }]
}, {
  name: "Linda is a perfect duplicate",
  urls: [{
    provider: "youtube",
    url: "http://youtube.com/lindaTube"
  }]
}, {
  name: "Linda is a perfect duplicate",
  urls: [{
    provider: "youtube",
    url: "http://youtube.com/lindaTube"
  }]
}]

var newdata = _.reduce(data, (result, value) => 
  _.values(
    _.mergeWith(
      _.keyBy(result, 'name'), 
      _.keyBy([value], 'name'), 
      (obj, src) => 
        _.isArray(obj) ? 
          _.values(_.merge(_.keyBy(obj, 'provider'), _.keyBy(src, 'provider'))) : 
          undefined   
    )
  ), []
);

console.log(newdata);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```